# Removing row in CSV file

Tags: java, file, csv, arraylist, rows

I have created an `ArrayList` called `entryList`. The method I am trying to create is that if you write `removeAllByDate()` and enter a date, the entire line with that date should be removed. The 
`entryList` in turn consists of entries (rows) and I have also created the method `getDate()`. I thought of writing something like this:

```
public void removeAllByDate(String datum) {
    for(Entry entry: entryList) {
        if (entry.getDate().contains(datum)) {
            entryList.remove(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone see why this does not work?

Comment: It's a self constructed class

Comment: The `entryList` is the data that is already present in the CSV and you need to delete some of the data ?

Comment: @ Trishul Singh Choudhary, exactly

Comment: @Melissa Loos The getDate() method only consists of return this.date

Comment: @Nickewas Hope you understand that you can't remove the data from csv where the data is already present. You can only create a new file which does not contain the data you want to remove.

Comment: @TrishulSinghChoudhary Oh, I may not have been clear about this but I am creating a new csvfile by stroring all the data from the old one and then writing it over to a new document, and this method is meant to do changes to that new document ie not containing the row with the specified date

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8, the method to use when conditionally removing elements from a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) is [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)). Your code will be as simple as the following:

```
entryList.removeIf(entry -> entry.getDate().contains(datum));
```

The original code is not working because removal of elements is not allowed while iterating over the collection, [see this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re).

Answer (score 0):

Nickewas, you're not being very forthcoming with Information:
- there are at least 2 different ArrayLists (e.g. java.util.ArrayList & java.util.Arrays.ArrayList)
- you don't mention *how* it doesn't work!

It may possibly be something to do with the following:
the for-each-loop uses an `Iterator` provided by your `Iterable` (entryList).
Maybe `entryList.remove(entry)` is having a side-effect on the Iterable?

Maybe this, or a variation thereof, would do it?

```
entryList.stream()
    .filter (entry -> entry.contains  (datum))  // Creates filtered Stream which...
    .forEach(entry -> entryList.remove(entry)); // ...maybe removes side-effect?
```

If not, you might have to use a `Collector` & iterate over the resulting `List`.